# Postgres routine declaring variable syntax error

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to get a postgres routine to return a table using the following code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_duration(duration INTEGER)
  RETURNS TABLE(id integer, name varchar, full_duration NUMERIC)
AS $$

DECLARE @lower_limit NUMERIC(10) = 28;
DECLARE @upper_limit NUMERIC(10) = 37.5;

BEGIN

IF duration = 45 THEN
  SET @lower_limit = 37.6;
  SET @upper_limit = 52.5;
END IF;

SELECT id, name, full_duration FROM duration WHERE up_limit = @upper_limit AND low_limit = @lower_limit;

END;
$$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

The issue is that I keep getting syntax error at or near "@" at the DECLARE line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put colons in DECLARE like

```
DECLARE @lower_limit NUMERIC(10) := 28;
```

This worked

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_duration(duration INTEGER)
 RETURNS  TABLE(id integer, name varchar, full_duration NUMERIC) AS
 $$
DECLARE
   lower_limit NUMERIC := 28;
    upper_limit NUMERIC := 37.5;
BEGIN
       IF duration = 45 THEN
      SET lower_limit = 37.6;
      SET upper_limit = 52.5;
    END IF;

    SELECT id, name, full_duration FROM duration WHERE up_limit = upper_limit AND low_limit = lower_limit;
END
$$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: still having the issue even with that on

Comment: May be you are using the DECLARE keyword twice. it is needed only once

Comment: I'm using the above. I tried with this

`DECLARE
    @lower_limit NUMERIC(10) := 28;
    @upper_limit NUMERIC(10) := 37.5;`
no go

Comment: I had the same issue and it did not work, I am new to postgresql and using pgAdmin4